# Want to know the raw sql query when user other than superuser logs in the system

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-1.3

I have an application which involves large number of users.
among those, some are staff members.

My problem

When a user from a certain group let say `A` logs in, it takes 5 minute to see the admin
screen (index page). I want to fix this problem.So the question is ,
What is the sql query  when a user from a certain group logs in the admin of the project.

I know how to see query

```
str(MyModel.objects.filter(name="my name").query)
```

but again not getting how to generate the query for that case

Answer (score 0):

Install [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and you will see all queries executed during user login.